# How to remove VsDebuggerCausalityData header section from SOAP request in WCF

Tags: wcf, soap, .net-3.5, wcf-security

I've added

```
 <system.diagnostics>
   <switches>
     <add name="Remote.Disable" value="1" />
   </switches>
 </system.diagnostics>
```

to my app.config, but the SOAP client still produce the header.

I'm using custombinding with messageversion Soap11 and httpstransport set.

Is there a simple way of removing it?

Answer (score 10):

I solved this by manually removing the behavior responsible for putting the vscasualitydata in.

```
        var vs = srv.Endpoint.Behaviors.Where((i) => i.GetType().Namespace.Contains("VisualStudio"));
        srv.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove((System.ServiceModel.Description.IEndpointBehavior)vs.Single());
```

Comment: As the extra headers only seem to get added when in debug mode you can also wrap this code in compiler preprocessor directives so the code is only added to debug builds ie. `#if DEBUG` ... `#endif`

Answer (score 6):

Try disabling the debugger support for WCF in Visual studio

Run this to uninstall -  vsdiag_regwcf.exe -u

It is located at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\`

You can reinstall the debugger support using -i parameter, and you can use the -s parameter to check whether or not debugger support is enabled.

For more details have a look at [this](http://aspdotnetdevelopment.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/how-to-remove-vsdebuggercausalitydata-from-a-soap-request/).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the "working" answer by `@Luiz Felipe` I came up with this slightly more robust solution:

```
var vs = client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.FirstOrDefault((i) => i.GetType().Namespace == "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink");
if (vs != null)
{
    client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(vs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the header is added when your configuration turns on wcf tracing or logging. turn them off and this will not be send.

Comment: There is no tracing or logging set in the configuration. If it's default on, how do I turn it off?

Comment: does it happen only when you run in debug mode, or also when you compile for release and run the exe outside of VS?

Comment: It does not happen outside VS. Is there a way to turn it off while debugging?

Comment: if it happens in VS even in release mode, and for the same .config it does not happen outside VS, I do not see a way to disable it.